# Shell cut grep command

Tags: shell

```
req=`bxp report change-summary $startDate $startDate  -iad -y | grep -A2 "Request ID"
```

The above script gives the below output

```
Request ID ------------ 10481066
```

I want to cut only the number `10481066`, I tried with number `grep` and other `cut` which is not working. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Is `Request ID ------------ 10481066` all in single line?

Comment: The number is the fourth *space*-separated field in the line. Should be extremely easy to get with [the `cut` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some alternatives to awk:

```
$ egrep -o '[0-9]+' <<<"This is a line with Request ID ------------ 10481066"
$ cut -d' ' -f4 <<<"Request ID ------------ 10481066"
$ egrep -o '[0-9]+$' <<<"This is a line with number 35546 with Request ID ------------ 10481066"
```

All above return `10481066`

PS: Cut default delimiter is tab, you need to declare with `-d` option space as delimiter in order cut to work with your data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your output `Request ID ------------ 10481066` is all in a single line, you can just replace `grep` with this `awk` command:

```
req=$(bxp report change-summary $startDate $startDate -iad -y|awk '/Request ID/{print $NF}')
```

Answer (score 0):

i just did this way

req=`bxp report change-summary $startDate $startDate  -iad -y | grep -A2 "Request ID" | grep -E "^[0-9]"`

any way thanks for your help

Comment: That is an inefficient way of doing it since it involves 2 additional commands.

Answer (score 0):

I would do manipulating the final string,

```
req="Request ID ------------ 10481066"
result=${req%-*}
```